# How to sort or reverse VecDeque without `make_contiguous()`?

Tags: rust, deque

I'd like to sort or reverse `VecDeque`. In Rust 1.48.0 or later, you can use `make_contiguous()` to mutably access the underlying slice to perform such operations:

```rust
v.make_contiguous().reverse(); //reverse
v.make_contiguous().sort(); //sort
```

However, I have to use Rust 1.42.0 in competitive programming. `unsafe` is allowed. Nightly Rust is not allowed.

I don't want to first collect `VecDeque` into `Vec`, then reverse or sort the result and finally collect `Vec` back to `VecDeque`, which seems unnecessarily very slow and verbose.

Is there any more elegant way?

Comment: Implement an in-place sorting algorithm such as heapsort, or quicksort if you can allocate some scratch space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine `as_mut_slices` and `rotate_right`.

```
fn sort_vecdeque<T: Ord>(x: &mut VecDeque<T>) {
    x.rotate_right(x.as_slices().1.len());
    assert!(x.as_slices().1.is_empty());
    x.as_mut_slices().0.sort();
}
```

This works because of how `VecDeque` is [implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.66.0/src/alloc/collections/vec_deque/mod.rs.html#113-114): It's a single memory allocation with holes either at the end and start (if `head > tail`), or in the middle (if `head < tail`).

- If the holes are at the start and end, the elements are already contiguous.
- If the hole is in the middle, the front of the deque is at the end of
  the allocation, and the back of the deque is at the beginning of the allocation. [`rotate_right`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.rotate_right) "pops the
  last k items and pushes them to the front.", i.e. it removes the
  elements at the start of the allocation and adds them to the elements
  at the back of the allocation, so the deque will be contiguous.
  (The way I read the docs, there's not really a guarantee that it will always be that way, which is why I like having the assert there.)

Lastly, if the deque is contiguous,
[`as_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.as_slices) (and its `mut` friend)
will return two slices, but the second one will be empty, all elements are in the first.

Also, using SO for a coding competition might be considered cheating.

Comment: Thank you. Why does this work? In particular, why `assert!()` always passes? (And thank you for your advice but don't worry this is not an ongoing contest and my alternative solution shown in OP is dirty but not that slow to affect the execution time very much.)

Comment: Explanation added.